# Match characters between two strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to select characters between two strings but it seems not working...

My input data :

```
// button

/* --------------- Paramétrage du composant --------------- */
// Thème du composant
$btn-theme: material;
// Couleur de fond des boutons
$btn-bg: #fff;
// Couleur de fond des boutons lors de l'hover
$btn-bg-hover: $main-color;
// Border radius des boutons
$btn-border-radius: 4px;
// Hauteur des boutons
$btn-height: 30px;
// Largeur des boutons
$btn-width: 30px;
// Hauteur des icônes SVG dans les boutons
$btn-svg-width: 66%;
// Paddin des boutons
$btn-padding: 0;
/* --------------- /Paramétrage du composant --------------- */
```

My regex : `/\$(.+):/g`

And I would like : `['btn-theme', 'btn-bg', 'btn-bg-hover', ...` as the result. However, my result always contains the dollar sign and the colon sign. e.g: `$btn-padding:`.

Comment: Can you add exact code you've tried?

Comment: How is it not working? What is the result you get?

Comment: I get `$btn-padding:, $btn-bg:` ...

Comment: [Looks fine to me.](https://regex101.com/r/eH2hG8/1) Make sure you're extracting the groups and not the complete match.

Comment: `/\$([^:]*):/g` is better regex if there are multiple of `$...:` per line

Comment: @tonymx227 And what did you want to get? .. .your question is quite unclear

Comment: this is a great tool to test regex in javascript https://regex101.com/

Comment: I don't want `$` and `:` in the result.

Comment: ^ you could do that part without regex, but you didn't share the code you are using right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```js
var origin = "// button \
/* --------------- Paramétrage du composant --------------- */\
// Thème du composant \
$btn-theme: material; \
// Couleur de fond des boutons \
$btn-bg: #fff; \
// Couleur de fond des boutons lors de l'hover \
$btn-bg-hover: $main-color; \
// Border radius des boutons \
$btn-border-radius: 4px; \
// Hauteur des boutons \
$btn-height: 30px; \
// Largeur des boutons \
$btn-width: 30px; \
// Hauteur des icônes SVG dans les boutons \
$btn-svg-width: 66%; \
// Paddin des boutons \
$btn-padding: 0; \
/* --------------- /Paramétrage du composant --------------- */";

var matches = origin.match(/\$([^:,^;]*):/g);


matches.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
 console.log(element.substring(1, element.length -1));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments you want this regex `(([-|A-z])*):`.

You want to match the tags, without `$` and `:` (according to the comments).

You can verify [here](https://regex101.com/r/eT3pH1/2) if this is what you want.